# Customize order history in open cart according to products

Tags: php, content-management-system, opencart

How can any one customize order `reports/order history/sales` of my product only not others.

Right now `opencart` provides detailed order history for all orders.

In short : **How can I view orders for my product only ?** is there any built in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no built in functionality for this at present. You're likely going to need to find a developer to custom build this or may be lucky and have one available in the extension store